# $T \to \infty$ solution behavior

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

Hello! I am having a little trouble solving the second part of the question which says "use the solution to determine how solutions behave as $\to\infty$. I have already found the solution of the differential equation using the Integrating Factor Method and found the solution to be:

$$ y = (t/3) - (1/9) + e^{(-2t)} + ce^{(-3t)}$$

I am now stuck on how to determine how the solution which, I found above, behaves as $t\to\infty$. The answer from the book says $y$ is asymptotic to $(t/3)−(1/9) $. But I am not sure how they got that answer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just compute:
$$
\lim_{t \to \infty} y(t)
$$

Comment: Oh ok. I just realized the last two terms go to zero then leaving me with the first two terms. Thanks!